# Open File as Other Program

Tags: nautilus, firefox, .desktop, xdg, file-roller

I want to configure Firefox to open .zip files with File-Roller.

In the options, I browse to `/usr/share/applications/file-roller.desktop` and it doesn’t open it as File Roller however `nautilus` easily does that.

Its like that for every program.

Which folder can I find all the applications to open files with because this folder doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the file `/usr/bin/file-roller` to make firefox to open zip files through file-roller.

Take a look at `/usr/bin` directory. Most of the important commands are resides in this particular directory.

Comment: thanks, do you also know how to remove apps from the original open with program? Wine put like 5 internet brwosers there along with 3 notepads and a bunch of other stuff taht makes it harder to find the useful programs.

Comment: sorry  i donno for wine.

Comment: Just accept the current answer and ask the above comment as another question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Firefox doesn't recognize/use the .desktop' files. Firefox calls the binaries itself so the only way to control that is from Firefox itself. In Preferences > Applications you will find a list with all the file types.

Now, other applications (KDE and GNOME which are the biggest DE) are compliant with the [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) (aka the thing that says how .desktop files should be written and interpreted) and these can be configured in bulks.